# Adding values of a particular property from all javascript objects in an array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object, math

I have an array of javascript objects:

`var myObjects = [{figure: 3}, {figure: 5}, {figure: 2}];`

I would like code that could give me a total of 10 based on the addition of all `figure` properties of objects in `myObjects`.

**What I've Tried/Done**

I could loop through using jQuery's `.each()` but I don't feel like iterating (and using a temporary 'store' variable) is the most elegant.

Obviously I could also do:

`myObjects[0] + myObjects[1]` etc. - but assume there is an arbitrary amount of objects.

I've done something similar for getting the minimum already:

`var lowest = Math.min.apply(null, myObjects.map(function (x) {
    return x['figure'];
}));`

But would like the equivalent for total.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [Array.prototype.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce):

```
var data = [{figure: 3}, {figure: 5}, {figure: 2}],
    sum = data.reduce(function(memo, c) { return memo + c.figure }, 0);
```

`reduce` is part of ECMAScript 5, so it is available in IE9+ and recent versions of all other browsers - see [this compatibility table](http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es5/#Array.prototype.reduce).

Comment: Why the downvote? Thanks a lot joews - will look into using reduce (never heard of it).

Comment: Please don't downvote without providing comments. It doesn't help anybody and, as it happens, this answer (and the other current answer) are correct.

Comment: +1 for answer... I think I'm needlessly trying to avoid temporary variable here aren't I.

Comment: I think this solution is much cleaner than an explicit loop. Surely an accumulation variable (`memo` in this case) is required to perform any kind of iterative summation?

Comment: I think you're right, there's no need for me to optimise it further. Sorted.